# Node.js - Proper way to add same block of code on event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templates, handlebars.js

I use Node.Js along with Express and Express HBS (Handlebars). And for users real time synchronization I use Socket.IO.

Let's say I code a web chat and each time someone hit the send message button I emit an event from client to the server. Next, the server will receive this event and emit a new event to all the others client, updating everyone one with the last message send by our first user.

Since we all want to be messy for the less and organize as possible, I would like to have a template file containing my new message skeleton. But after that I don't understand what I've to do. My first thought was render this template either :

- from the client with data send by Socket.IO.
- or from the server and send back the html rendered to the client through Socket.IO.

But it seems that's not recommendable ways, as far as I am in my research.

What I would like to avoid is :

- HTML Skeleton inline in the client JS code receiving the new message from Socket.IO.
- that everyone ask to the server (ajax request for example) the same message just after receiving the info from Socket.IO that it is one available. What if I had 10,000 users sending and receiving message ?
- that we put the block of code in a `<script></script>`, get it inside the js and put it at the right place in the DOM when I need it. Best approach I found for the moment, but what if I need a lot of this sort of thing ? I don't like the idea that I could have a lot of blocks code at the end of my DOM just in case I could grab it and use it, maybe or maybe not.
- Reload the entire page each time a message is send.

Actually, my current project is not a chat but I use this as an example. Keep in mind that the block of code I want to add to the DOM on events could be more heavy than just a chat message.

What is your thoughts about all of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is send the template earlier on as a string, compile it and store as template (in some Map). Then when a new message comes in, you just need to pass in the data to get the html content where you can then set as innerHtml to some div at your desired location.

If you need my thoughts i will say the stack may be an issue. You want to realise a reactive feeling in your application but at the expense of your api, as it continously compile those templates to send to your various clients as html.

Another bad effect to consider is those html tend to be heavy when sending to the various clients, whereares sending just the data that changed is quite light weight.

Best approach will be use a client framework that is best suited for such reactivity you need. A library/framework like React will permit you manage the events, and show new data using components available on the client. You will only need to send data concerning the event like the sender info and content.

Check out this page on handlebars website specify best suits for handlebars. https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/when-to-use-handlebars.html

Comment: Yeah, actually, you open my eyes. On my way to learn React :)